# WebBrowser自動ログインについて

Tags: c#

WindowsデスクトップアプリケーションでWEBサイトにログインするのは危険ですか？
色々なブログにはこのように書かれていますが、VisualC#WebBrowserはIE7と古いので危険性を感じました。WEB APIは初心者です。

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string currentUrl = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
    textBox3.Text = currentUrl;

    if (currentUrl.StartsWith("https://login.yahoo.co.jp/config/login"))
    {
        string id="userid";
        string pass ="userpass";
        webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("yahoo_id")[0].InnerText = id;
        webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("password")[0].InnerText = pass;
        webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("auto_login")[0].SetAttribute("checked", "true");
        webBrowser1.Document.Forms[0].InvokeMember("submit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
VisualC#WebBrowserはIE7と古い
```

WebBrowserコントロールのUser-Agent文字列を確認するとIE7ぽい文字列ですが、実際には互換モードになっているだけでIE7そのものではありません。その点では、Internet Explorerを普通に使うのとリスクに違いはありません。

WebBrowserコントロールを使って外部のWebサイトを操作をする場合、アプリケーションがアプリケーションの外部とやりとりする際のデータの扱いに注意してください。検査されていない入力値をWebBrowserコントロールに渡さない、出力データにCookieなどの機密データを含まない、など。

Comment: 上記の内容から、WindowsデスクトップアプリケーションでWEBログインしても問題ないものと判断しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! JAPANの利用経験がないため確実なことは言えませんが、`WebBrowser`コントロールとInternet Explorerはcookieが共有されています。ですので、Internet Explorer側で自動ログインにチェックを付けた上でログインを行っておけば、`WebBrowser`コントロール側でも自動ログインされるようになりませんか？

---

`WebBrowser`コントロールに対して処理を書き込むことに不安を感じられるのでしたら、Internet Explorerにて自動ログインの設定を行ってしまうことで、アプリケーション側では処理しなくても済みます。処理を書かなければ不安は解消されるかと思います。

`WebBrowser`コントロールが既定でIE7モードとなるのはもちろん互換のためです。[Browser Emulation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation)に記載されているレジストリ値を書き込むことで動作モードを切り替えることができます。

Comment: sayuri様、画像圧縮の件はお世話になりました。Windows10のIEedgeはC#WebBrowserとリンクしてませんでした。

Comment: @まめたろう Internet Explorerで試されたのでしょうか？Edgeは名前の通り別ブラウザーなので共有されません。

Comment: InternetExplorerで試しました、ログインできました